# Ghost USB flash drive on W10 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have an old 128 Mb USB flash drive, FAT32 formatted.

When connected to a Windows 7 x64 machine, it can be used with no problem.
When connected to another machine running Windows 10 v1909 x64, it does not appear into the explorer. It is there in the Disk Manager, its volume can be deleted, created again, but cannot be formatted.

At this point, connecting it back to the Windows 7 machine makes a popup appear that asks to format it. Once done (NTFS format), it can be used on this machine without any problem.

But connected back on the Windows 10 machine, same problem again.

What's happening here, and what can I do to solve this ?

Comment: If you are familiar with command line and `diskpart` tool then try the method using diskpart as in [this blog](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-repair-corrupted-pen-drive-or-sd-card/).

Comment: Or try Windows *diskmgmt.msc* or a third-party tool such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/, to change the partition scheme and to format if you prefer a GUI.

Comment: format it ntfs on the w7 machine, see if W10 can see it now.

Comment: @Moab: as detailled in the question, this does not change anything

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik : Thank you, I will try this. But do you know why this happens ? I didn't do anything special with this drive but copying files to/from it.

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons, such as removing the device without ejecting it, or a bad device, which format would *not* help.